# Https and http Image URL Not loading in silverlight

Tags: cross-domain, silverlight-5.0

in my silverlight application i have two image tags one is with http image url and other one is https image url

in local system the http enabled image url is loading but the https image url is not loading.

when i host the application in https enabled site, it displays the https enabled image url but not displaying the http enabled imageurl

how to handle this issue.

```
my client access policy :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
<cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
        <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
            <domain uri="http://*" />
            <domain uri="https://*" />
        </allow-from>
        <grant-to>
            <resource include-subpaths="true" path="/">
            </resource>
        </grant-to>
    </policy>
</cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>


my cross domain policy:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<! DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-   policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the Silverlight URL restrictions,Please check if you miss something to help you out from here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

You need to explicitly enable this with a security policy file. See Network Security Access Restrictions in Silverlight topic for more information.

Comment: yes! i read this post already... and http and https are in allowed scheme of images. i did n't understand wat wd b the issue. if you had this.. could you brief on that.. thanks pratik..

Comment: @Shankar you should read more carefully then... Cross scheme URL are not allowed for "Image class, MediaElement class for progressive downloads (media, images, ASX, etc.)".

Comment: @Shankar I have to drop this idea of using images from HTTPS location no alternative apart from managing policy creating and the HTTPS request through firewall which will never be possible if the application is big or banking application.