# Silverlight not accessing content when using https

Tags: c#, silverlight, https

I have a SL app that has https and http endpoints. If i access the endpoint on http, then just have a screen which loads an external image 
`http://somedomain.com/domaimage.jpg`

It will work fine.

If i access the SL app on https:// then load the same image it won't even attempt to make the web request for the image.

Why when SL is running on https i doesn't request external content? I have this in my clientaccesspolicy.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <access-policy>
      <cross-domain-access>
          <policy>
              <allow-from http-request-headers="*" http-methods="*">
          <domain uri="http://*"/>
          <domain uri="https://*"/>
              </allow-from>
              <grant-to>
                  <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
              </grant-to>
          </policy>
      </cross-domain-access>`
  
and this is my crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now using an image proxy to access external content, if it helps anyone

ImageProxy.ashx

```
public class ImageUrlProxy : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string url = context.Request.Headers["Url"];
            var client = new WebClient();
            byte[] imageDataBytes = client.DownloadData(url);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json;";
            context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imageDataBytes));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Helper class:

```
public static class ImageProxyHelper
{
    public static void GetImageByProxy(string url, Action<BitmapImage> callback)
    {
        if (callback == null) return;
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Error == null)
            {
                var buffer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte[]>(args.Result);
                var im = new BitmapImage() { CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None };
                im.SetSource(new MemoryStream(buffer));
                callback(im);
            }
        };
        client.Headers["Url"] = url;
        client.DownloadStringAsync(UrlBuilder("ImageUrlProxy.ashx"));
    }


    public static Uri UrlBuilder(string fragment)
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Application.Current.Host.Source.Scheme,
            Application.Current.Host.Source.Host,
            Application.Current.Host.Source.Port, fragment);
        return uriBuilder.Uri;
    }
}
```

Then from silverlight:

```
ImageProxyHelper.GetImageByProxy("http://externaldomain.com/image.jpg", p=>{
        //Do something here
})
```

This can be extended to return any external content ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are having the same problem as this question

[Https and http Image URL Not loading in silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718099/https-and-http-image-url-not-loading-in-silverlight)

It is down to cross scheme calls in silverlight